# Extract text from a string using a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I would like to extract the value inside the *acquireTest* parenthesis from the following string:

```
format.getControl(val.acquireTest(xyzTest));
```

Above should return: *xyzTest*

The value always comes after the word ***acquireTest*** and will always be in parenthesis.

More examples:

```
key.setUp(value.acquireTest(abcTest));
```

Above example should return: *abcTest*

```
app.getMax((Integer.parseInt(va.acquireTest(getValue))));
```

Above example should return: *getValue*

I have tried the following regular expression:

```
\.acquireTest\((.*?)\)
```

However, it does not give me the exact value I am looking for.

Any help is deeply appreciate it!

Comment: What does it return if not the exact value? Have you looked into the group 1?

Comment: "*However, it does not give me the exact value I am looking for.*" this regex looks fine (assuming there are no linebreaks between parenthesis since `.` can't match it by default - it can be changed though). Can you show us how are you using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below

```
        List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("acquireTest\\((.*?)\\)");
        Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher("format.getControl(val.acquireTest(xyzTest));\\n");

        while (regexMatcher.find()) {
           matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
        }

        for(String str:matchList) {
           System.out.println(str);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Learn something new about regex today :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
final String regex = "acquireTest\\((\\w*)";
final String string = "format.getControl(val.acquireTest(xyzTest));\n"
     + "key.setUp(value.acquireTest(abcTest));\n"
     + "app.getMax((Integer.parseInt(va.acquireTest(getValue))));";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(1));

}
```

check the demo at [online compiler](http://ideone.com/VAazHd)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you want to extract

```
(val.acquireTest(xyzTest)) from

format.getControl(val.acquireTest(xyzTest));
```

If it's true, you should do

```
\(.*\.acquireTest\(.*\)\)
```

Tell me what you get and if it's OK for you.

Cheers
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("acquireTest\\((\\w+)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("app.getMax((Integer.parseInt(va.acquireTest(getValue))));");
    if (matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Does this works for you?